# How to properly implement XAML INotifyPropertyChanged to prevent GDI leaks

Tags: wpf, binding, gdi, inotifypropertychanged

We have an application which uses WPF to generate an image that shows a workflow, this is very old and seemed to work fine until recently when we began experiencing GDI leaks. I'm not familiar with WPF or GDI leaks but after some searching around it could be the case to have something to do with WPF bindings. And the articles mentioned implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to all classes that are binding on the XAML. And so I did but the problem still remains.

I tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged to the problematic classes the memory profilers mention. Also tried to setting the DataContext property of the user control to null.

Below you see the dominators of the new objects created between two memory snapshots.

[image: a busy cat]

Below you see the xaml and code behind of the dominator.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Priox.Core.Graph.UserControls
{
    public partial class IndicatorClock : UserControl
    {
        public enum ClockTypes
        {
            None,
            FixSla,
            ResponseSla,
            FixOla,
            ResponseOla
        };

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ClockTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ClockType", typeof(ClockTypes),
            typeof(IndicatorClock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ClockTypes.None));

        public ClockTypes ClockType
        {
            get { return (ClockTypes)GetValue(ClockTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ClockTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        internal bool IsClockVisible { get; set; }

        public Visibility ClockVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsClockVisible)
                    return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public double ClockBorderThickness
        {
            get
            {
                return 1.5;
            }
        }

        public double ClockTimeThickness
        {
            get
            {
                return 2.0;
            }
        }

        public Brush ClockColor
        {
            get
            {
                switch (ClockType)
                {
                    case ClockTypes.FixSla:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
                    case ClockTypes.ResponseSla:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkMagenta);
                    case ClockTypes.FixOla:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                    case ClockTypes.ResponseOla:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateGray);
                }
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
        }

        public IndicatorClock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="Priox.Core.Graph.UserControls.IndicatorClock"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockVisibility, FallbackValue=Visible}">




            <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.7"/>
        </Grid.Effect>

        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockBorderThickness, FallbackValue=4.0}" Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockColor, FallbackValue=Red}" />

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockColor, FallbackValue=Red}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Line Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Y1="0" Y2="1" Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockColor, FallbackValue=Red}" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockTimeThickness, FallbackValue=8.0}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="90"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Line Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Y1="0" Y2="1" Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockColor, FallbackValue=Red}" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ClockTimeThickness, FallbackValue=8.0}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I fix this to not GDI leak anymore.

EDIT: Adjusted the code according the suggestion of Clemens, but the usercontrol is still showing up as the dominator.

Comment: Besides that you don't seem to fire the PropertyChanged event anywhere, it makes no sense to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a class that derives from DependencyObject (like UserControl). The properties declared in a DependencyObject-derived class should be dependency properties, which have their own change notification mechanism.

Comment: It is also a bug to set `this.DataContext = this;` in a UserControl when it exposes bindable properties. The usual DataContext-based Binding like `<IndicatorClock ClockType="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}"/>` won't work anymore. Instead of explicitly setting the DataContext, use RelativeSource Bindings in the UserControl's XAML, like `Fill="{Binding ClockColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

Comment: Adjusted the code to your suggestions, but it is still showing up as a dominator. Not sure if I did it correctly though.

Comment: My comments weren't meant to provide a solution. Just saying that implementing INPC (or data binding) hasn't got anything to do with your actual problem. It makes no sense to implement it.

Comment: OK I also thought implementing the INPC would be useless, but several sources said something about this to prevent GDI leaks. I did not find any other suggestions to fix my issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be a MVVM architecture and i recommand you to use a MVVM Franmework like MVVM light it will help to avoid a lot of problems and do a better code.
http://www.mvvmlight.net/
With MVVMLight you don't need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged the framework is doing everything.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved my issue it had nothing to do with how the XAML looked, the reason why I looked at the XAML was because all the memory profilers I used told me that those were the problem. The actual problem was that the UserControl was set to an object that wasn't used by the application at all. So the XAML was not garbage collected and increased the GDI count this way.

```
var source = new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters())
{
    RootVisual = this
};
```